# Using SendData results in a mangled string when received

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to send a string between two Delphi forms using code adapted from here: http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/wm_copydata.htm.

The string that is displayed by the receiver is partially garbage. I suspect this is because of Unicode   I issues when Delphi 2010 is communicating with the Windows API.

I want to be able to handle Unicode if possible.

I have been unable to figure out where in the code below a cast is wrong.  Any help?

**Sending form:**

```
procedure TForm1.gridDetailsDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  StringToSend : String;
  CopyDataStruct : TCopyDataStruct;
begin
  StringToSend := StringGrid1.Cells[0, StringGrid1.Row];
  CopyDataStruct.dwData := 0;
  CopyDataStruct.cbData := 1 + Length(StringToSend) ;
  CopyDataStruct.lpData := PChar(StringToSend) ;
  SendDataToAppearanceForm(copyDataStruct) ;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendDataToAppearanceForm(const CopyDataStruct: TCopyDataStruct) ;
var
  ReceiverHandle : THandle;
begin
  ReceiverHandle := FindWindow(PChar('TForm2'), nil);
  if (ReceiverHandle <> 0) then
    SendMessage(receiverHandle, WM_COPYDATA, Integer(Handle), Integer(@CopyDataStruct)) ;
end;
```

**Receiving form:** (Which results in the edit box containing a part of the string, but then garbage.)

```
procedure TForm2.WMCopyData(var Msg: TWMCopyData);
var
  S: String;
begin
  edText.Text := PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
end;  { WMCopyData }
```

Comment: Would you consider using COM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting `cbData` incorrectly.  This is the number of bytes and not the number of characters.

The `+1` is needed since your receiver is interpreting it as a null-terminated string.  Therefore your code should read:

```
(1 + Length(StringToSend))*SizeOf(Char)
```

Alternatively you could, at the receiving end, make use of `SetString()` and `cbdata` to avoid the need for the `+1`.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); // Project1.exe
var
  CDS: TCopyDataStruct;
begin
  CDS.dwData := 0;
  CDS.cbData := (length(Edit1.Text) + 1) * sizeof(char);
  CDS.lpData := PChar(Edit1.Text);

  SendMessage(FindWindow(nil, 'RecForm'),
    WM_COPYDATA, Integer(Handle), Integer(@CDS));
end;

procedure TForm1.WndProc(var Message: TMessage); // Project2.exe
begin
  inherited;
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_COPYDATA:
      begin
        Edit1.Text := PChar(TWMCopyData(Message).CopyDataStruct.lpData);
        Message.Result := Integer(True);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

to copy and it works. The difference between this code and yours is that, since one Unicode character is *two* bytes long, the `cbData` member needs to be the number of characters in the string *times two*, that is, times `sizeof(char)`. In addition, you need to add a whole character so that the null terminator is sent along with the string! Otherwise the receiver will not know when the string ends!

Comment: +1 especially for the SizeOf(char). And congrats on reaching trusted status (maybe it happened earlier, but I just spotted it now).

Comment: @Marjan: Well, I am at 19 981 right now, but very soon. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Andreas: They must have changed to rounding then instead of truncing, coz your "flair" says 20k...

Comment: I know of at least one person who, when crossed by someone, will go to that someone's profile and downvote every question and answer they think is in the slightest wrong or not useful... Of course, it may also just be someone having a bad day or getting frustrated over not finding a solution to his problem and swatting answers like annoying flies.

Comment: @Marjan: Thank you for your reply. Well, for the last months or so, almost every answer I has given has been downvoted, so I feel very confused about this. It feels personal. It's not fun at all...

Comment: @Andreas: It might be personal, I don't know. I would try to put it out of my mind if I were you. If it is some kind of personal vendetta, it says more about the downvoter than about you. Plus, there simply isn't anything you can do about it. Even if the downvoter were to come forward and tell you who (s)he is and why (s)he is pissed off, chances are there is nothing you could say that would change his/her mind.